# Oracle SQL query nested select functions with a join

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get a query that has the headers "a_program, app_col, count, load_fy". Trying to set "a_program" to be only a very select subset of the existing column "current_program_code". "app_col, subject_id, and load_yr" are all existing columns in table "FT_a". Now, the tricky bit, is I only want responses from "FT_a" that don't exist in table "FT_d". "FT_a" and "FT_d" both have a "subject_id" column.

Been trying to run the following.

```
select a_program, A.app_col,count(distinct A.subject_id),A.load_fy
from 
(
select A.app_col,A.subject_id, A.load_fy,

case
when A.current_program_code in ('234','ABC', 'DDD', 'TTT', 'SSS', 'PPP', 'DDM') then 'POP'
when A.current_program_code in ('AND', 'YOU', 'ARE', 'IT', 'INT','CAO','PAP') then 'ROM'
when A.current_program_code in ('ORD') then 'SAG'
when A.current_program_code in ('TO', 'SPA', 'SAP', 'SLA', 'SIS') then 'FOR'
when A.current_program_code in ('TXT', 'XLS', 'JAN') then 'FAV'
when A.current_program_code is null then 'Unknown'
else A.current_program_code
end
as a_program

from ft_a A 
left join ft_d D
on A.subject_id=D.subject_id
where D.subject_id is null
and A.load_fy='2015'
)
group by a_program, A.app_col, A.load_fy;
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."LOAD_FY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I can only imagine I'm missing a stupid comma somewhere... any help?

Comment: Sorry, not a syntax error, so it's no missing comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say if you have other problems, but the first thing I notice is that you're referring to the `a` alias in the outer query, but the `a` alias is only in scope in the inner query.

So just remove the `a` alias from the outer `select` and `group by` clauses (first and last lines of the SQL statement), and try again:

```
select a_program, app_col,count(distinct subject_id),load_fy
from 
(
select A.app_col,A.subject_id, A.load_fy,

case
when A.current_program_code in ('234','ABC', 'DDD', 'TTT', 'SSS', 'PPP', 'DDM') then 'POP'
when A.current_program_code in ('AND', 'YOU', 'ARE', 'IT', 'INT','CAO','PAP') then 'ROM'
when A.current_program_code in ('ORD') then 'SAG'
when A.current_program_code in ('TO', 'SPA', 'SAP', 'SLA', 'SIS') then 'FOR'
when A.current_program_code in ('TXT', 'XLS', 'JAN') then 'FAV'
when A.current_program_code is null then 'Unknown'
else A.current_program_code
end
as a_program

from ft_a A 
left join ft_d D
on A.subject_id=D.subject_id
where D.subject_id is null
and A.load_fy='2015'
)
group by a_program, app_col, load_fy;
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I had been messing with this stupid script for 2 hours. You're awesome.